# Disable Javascript selection On A Calendar

Tags: javascript

I need to disable all other days within a calendar but fridays, they still need to be visible but not clickable.

This is the site I got the example from:
[Here](http://javascriptcalendar.org/javascript-date-picker.php)

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify jsDatePick js file, and add that feature like this:

```
if (this.oConfiguration.disableNotFriday){ 
    if (parseInt(oDay.getDay()) != 5  ){
      disabledDayFlag = true;
      aDayDiv.setAttribute("isJsDatePickDisabled",1);
}
}
```

You also need to add to configuration:

```
this.oConfiguration.disableNotFriday    = (aConf["disableNotFriday"] != null) ? aConf["disableNotFriday"] : false;
```

and on javascripty call object like this:

```
new JsDatePick({
        useMode:2,
        target:"inputField",
        dateFormat:"%d-%M-%Y",
        disableNotFriday:true
    });
```

Example is set here: http://jqfiles.webege.com/calendar.html

Is this what you want?

Comment: No problem, if you have some question just asked.